# ASP.NET: Validate file size (width and height) before upload

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, validation

Is there some way to validate the image size (height and width) before upload it to server?

I think is using Javascript but I don't know how. Or maybe with some client asp.net validator.

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can't be done using javascript on the client-side. Maybe you'll find a file upload component written in flash, silverlight or similar that allows to restrict the files being uploaded by the type, size and dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

You simply cannot know the file size in JS on the client.

What you *could* do is inspect the file size once the request arrives on the server, then cancel the transfer if the expected file size is over a certain limit:

In your upload module's BeginRequest:

```
   HttpWorkerRequest workerRequest = (HttpWorkerRequest)context.GetType().GetProperty("WorkerRequest",  BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(context, null);
        // Indicates if the worker request has a body

        if (workerRequest.HasEntityBody())
        {
            // Get the byte size of the form post. 
           long contentLength = long.Parse((workerRequest.GetKnownRequestHeader(HttpWorkerRequest.HeaderContentLength)));
            if (contentLength > MAX_UPLOAD_FILE_SIZE * 1024 )
                  {
                   workerRequest.CloseConnection();
                   context.Response.Redirect(SomeErrorPage);
                  }
        }
```

Haven't tested this yet, but theoretically it might work

EDIT: never mind, i'm an idiot. I thought he meant checking the FILE SIZE, not IMAGE SIZE

Answer (score 1):

I found [this Javascript snippet](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=5781) and worked on my system (IE 7.0.6001.18000). You should be aware and check for possible cross browser problems.

```
var tempImage;

function showDimensions() {
    var imageName = document.forms[0].elements['myFile'].value;
    if (imageName != '') {
        imageName = 'file:///' + escape(imageName.split('\\').join('/'));
        imageName = imageName.split('%3A').join(':');

        tempImage = new Image();
        tempImage.onload = getDimensions;
        tempImage.src = imageName + '?randParam=' + new Date().getTime();
        // append a timestamp to avoid caching issues - which happen if you
        // overwrite any image with one of different dimensions, and try to
        // get the dimensions again even with cache settings to max,
        // in both ff and ie!
    }
}

function getDimensions() {
    alert(tempImage.width + ' x ' + tempImage.height);
}
```

Comment: I won't work for a miriad of security problems. Also in IE7+ the value of an Upload File element will not contain the entire path anymore.Just the name of the file.

Comment: +1: I just ran this code here using IE7 and worked; anyways, its good to be warned about this possible problems, ty

Comment: Strange that you could get the complete file path in IE7. I distinctly remember having to rewrite our upload component because of this behaviour change... maybe some future IE7 update reverted to the old way